# Add text after expression <%$ ... %>

Tags: asp.net

In my ASPX page I've this:

```
<h3>
    <asp:HyperLink runat="server"
        NavigateUrl="<%$ Resources:Path, Article%>"
        Text='<%# Eval("title") %>' />
</h3>
```

For the `NavigateUrl` attribute I want to specify an ID like

```
NavigateUrl="<%$ Resources:Path, Article%>?id=4"
```

But when I do that the expression is not precessed by the ASP parser.

How can I do that?

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive: Yes, me too. did you have a better way?

Comment: i'd co-sign the other approach. meaning, define the link programmatically.  hope that worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this in markup. You have a server control here -- give it an ID (say, `ID="NavigationLink"`, and then do something like this in your .cs file:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I'm guessing that "4" was just an example here, so fill that piece in with a function you can call to create the proper ID.
    NavigationLink.NavigateUrl = Properties.Resources.Path + Properties.Resources.Article + "?id=4" 
}
```

**Edit:** I'm assuming that when you say `<%$ Resources:Path, Article%>` that you're trying to reference the `Path` and `Article` entries in your resources file, but upon further reflection, it's hard to tell exactly what you're doing. Can you be more specific here?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a protected function in the code behind class and call it from the markup. Like this:

```
<h3>
    <asp:HyperLink runat="server"
        NavigateUrl="<%# GetNavigateUrl(Eval("ID")) %>" <%-- Passing an ID as a parameter for example --%>
        Text='<%# Eval("title") %>' />
</h3>
```

Code behind:

```
// Again, idObj is just an example. Any info from the data item can be passed here
protected string GetNavigateUrl(object idObj)
{
    int id = (int)idObj;
    string urlFromResources = // retrieving the url from resources
    return urlFromResources + '?ID=' + id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [retrieve the resource values programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227982.aspx), in your code-behind, and set the NavigateUrl property from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try String.Format...

```
<% =String.Format({0}?id={1}, Request.ApplicationPath, 4) %>
```

It looks like you're mixing some other language into this (javascript?).

Also, don't forget to give your server-side controls an ID.